# Fluid dynamics (buoyancy )

Tags: homework-and-exercises, fluid-dynamics

This is the image of a question that I got when I was going through past year papers of INJSO. In this problem should not B be the correct option as the buoyancy will make the stones apparent weight lesser than its actual weight? I think that there shouldn't be any difference in the 2nd weighing machine. Please guide me.

[image]

Comment: Hello and welcome to Physics SE! Please note that homework-like questions should **ask about a specific physics concept** and **show some effort** to work through the problem. We want our questions to be useful to the broader community, and to future users. **We don't answer homework or worked example type questions.**

Comment: See [this Meta post on asking homework/exercise questions](https://physics.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/714/how-do-i-ask-homework-questions-on-physics-stack-exchange) and [this Meta post for "check my work" problems](https://meta.physics.stackexchange.com/questions/6093/should-any-check-my-work-questions-be-made-on-topic) for more guidance on how to edit your question to make it better.

Comment: The net force on the stone must remain zero. The gravitational field hasn't changed, so the total lift on the stone can't change.

Answer (score 3):

I think C would be the correct answer. It is true that the bouyancy will make the apparent weight of the stone smaller. However, as there is a force from the water pushing the stone up, there must be an equal and opposite force pushing the water down. This is due to Newton's Third Law. Therefore, the apparent weight of the water will increase

Comment: That is correct, @EwanMiller.  I have done a very similar demo in the class room in front of students, where I balanced a beaker of water on the pan of the balance.  When I slowly poked my finger in the water, without touching anything other than the water, Newton's third law intervened, causing the pan of the balance to go down.